# MSP430FR2433 SPI data corrupted

Tags: spi, uart, msp430, texas-instruments, baudrate

I'm currently working with MSP430FR2433 Micro. I want to interface this micro with the following modules:

- LCD screen via SPI (https://www.orientdisplay.com/store/amc0802br-b-y6wfdy-spi-8x2-character-lcd-module-spi-interface/)
- Keypad via GPIO's
- RealTerm software via UART.

**Purpose**: The user enters a 4-digit code (say 7777) via the Keypad. The micro should read the code, then compare it, then if a match should turn on LED1 (on the dev board), and sent the entered code via UART to RealTerm software.

**Problem**: I'm very positive that the problem is with the clock config.

**Issue**: When I turn ON UART, SPI doesn't work. When I turn OFF Uart, SPI works.

**Datasheets**: https://www.ti.com/product/MSP430FR2433

**Note**: When I say doesn't work, the following happens:

- My SPI is connected to an LCD screen. I'm supposed to see "Code in?" on my LCD via SPI but I got "Co9g0coc". As you can see, the data is corrupted.
- I'm entering 7777 as a code. I'm supposed to see '7777Z' in the RealTerm. But I see Ÿ777Z or 7·Ÿ7ª or 777·Z.

I have attached the main functions of two different codes. Could you please let me know how to make SPI and UART work?

Uart works SPI doesn't

```
int main(void)
{
    WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD; // Stop watchdog timer

    PM5CTL0 &= ~LOCKLPM5; // Disable the GPIO power-on default high-impedance mode

    FRAM_counter_ptr = (unsigned int *)FRAM_counter_static;     // always pointed to 1800 location. This is where counter is located
// Configure UART pins
    P2SEL0 |= BIT5 | BIT6;                    // set 2-UART pin as second function

    // Configure UART
    UCA1CTLW0 |= UCSWRST;
    UCA1CTLW0 |= UCSSEL__SMCLK;

    UCA1BR0 = 52;                                    // 8000000/16/9600
    UCA1BR1 = 0x00;
    UCA1MCTLW = 0x4900 | UCOS16 | UCBRF_1;

    UCA1CTLW0 &= ~UCSWRST;                    // Initialize eUSCI
    UCA1IE |= UCRXIE;                         // Enable USCI_A0 RX interrupt

    //configure SPI

    P1SEL0 |= BIT4 | BIT5 | BIT6; // set 3-SPI pin as second function

    UCA0CTLW0 |= UCSWRST;                     // **Put state machine in reset**
                                      // 4-pin, 8-bit SPI master

    //UCA1CTLW0 |= UCMST|UCSYNC|UCCKPL|UCMSB|UCMODE_1|UCSTEM;   // Clock polarity high, MSB
    UCA0CTLW0 |= UCMST|UCSYNC|UCMSB|UCMODE_1|UCSTEM;            // Clock polarity low, Clock Phase 1, MSB
    UCA0CTLW0 |= UCSSEL__SMCLK;               // SMCLK
    UCA0BR0 = 0x08;                           // /2,fBitClock = fBRCLK/(UCBRx+1).
    UCA0BR1 = 0;                              //
    UCA0MCTLW = 0;                            // No modulation
    UCA0CTLW0 &= ~UCSWRST;                    // **Initialize USCI state machine**
    UCA0IE |= UCRXIE;                         // Enable USCI_A1 RX interrupt
    //TXData_SPI = 0x01;                            // Holds TX data


    //UCA0IE |= UCTXIE;                      // Enable TX interrupt
```

SPI works Uart doesn't

```
    WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD; // Stop watchdog timer

    PM5CTL0 &= ~LOCKLPM5; // Disable the GPIO power-on default high-impedance mode

    FRAM_counter_ptr = (unsigned int *)FRAM_counter_static;     // always pointed to 1800 location. This is where counter is located

       // Configure UART pins
    P2SEL0 |= BIT5 | BIT6;                    // set 2-UART pin as second function

    // Configure UART
    UCA1CTLW0 |= UCSWRST;                     // Put eUSCI in reset
    UCA1CTLW0 |= UCSSEL__SMCLK;
    // Baud Rate calculation
    UCA1BR0 = 0x08;                              // 1000000/115200 = 8.68
    UCA1MCTLW = 0xB700;                       // 1000000/115200 - INT(1000000/115200)=0.68
                                              // UCBRSx value = 0xD6 (See UG)
    UCA1BR1 = 0;
    UCA1CTLW0 &= ~UCSWRST;                    // Initialize eUSCI

P1SEL0 |= BIT4 | BIT5 | BIT6; // set 3-SPI pin as second function

UCA0CTLW0 |= UCSWRST; // **Put state machine in reset**
UCA0CTLW0 |= UCMST|UCSYNC|UCCKPL|UCMSB|UCMODE_0; // 3-pin, 8-bit SPI master
// Clock polarity high, MSB
UCA0CTLW0 |= UCSSEL__SMCLK; // SMCLK
UCA0BR0 = 0x01; // /2,fBitClock = fBRCLK/(UCBRx+1).
UCA0BR1 = 0; //
UCA0MCTLW = 0; // No modulation
UCA0CTLW0 &= ~UCSWRST; // **Initialize USCI state machine**
UCA0IE |= UCRXIE;
```

Comment: Those two piecs of code indeed use different configuration settings. Why don't you combine those settings for UCA0 and UCA1 that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the problem. The SPI apparently was working just fine. It was the LCD that has the issue.

What I didn't take into consideration is that the clock speed changed from 1MHz before to 8Mhz. Its 8 times faster, so I have to increase my delays, like delay after chip select, the transition from command mode to data mode, etc. This is why I was missing 1 or 2 characters.

The initialization of the LCD was also ruined because the delays weren't enough as the clock speed increased 8 times. That's why sometimes, the display wouldn't clear or the cursor wouldn't reset, etc.

I recalculated the delays and ran the code 6 times. Not once I missed any characters. Before that this wasn't the case. I am having a hard time believing this.

Can anyone corroborate my theory? (I'll close the issue after) or is it just luck. I did reduce the delays and saw the same issue pop up.

Thank you